# How to draw a simple image with sharpdx winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, 2d, directx, sharpdx

I've looked around online and I cant find anything beginner friendly. I know you're supposed to know about directx to get into this library, but this is my entry point to learn, and I can't learn without knowing what anything is or having any simple full examples.

I already have the image as a system.drawing.bitmap in a loop, so I just need the simplest possible way of drawing an image with sharpdx direct2d1 with some description of what anything is, please. I dont know what a device context is, I dont know what a render target is, I dont know what any of it is - I just know I want to use the hardware acceleration to draw full-window images, ideally with the ability to add shader filters.

The reason I'm trying to use sharpdx is because even drawing with my own Graphics object is extremely slow for bigger images, coming constantly from a webcam.

Comment: I think that your render code can be optimized.

Comment: I bet it could be somewhat, but the webcam Im talking about is actually a capture card, so I'm talking constant HD images with nice scaling and filters. Simply rendering without any form of scaling (only a 480p image) works flawlessly at full speed, but that misses the point of what I'm doing.

Comment: Hardware acceleration is more about vertices, triangles, hidden surfaces, shaders, computation, than just rendering or "drawing" images. Add to that the cost of transferring between CPU and GPU. If you have already a GDI bitmap (which is not a resource on the GPU but on the CPU), there's little you can accelerate. Adding shaders would be indeed a reason to move to GPU. You should learn a bit of DirectX/Direct2D before SharpDx. It's difficult to help w/o a real piece of code explaining what the problems are and SharpDx is dead so may not be the best choice.

Comment: How would you recommend speeding things up then? The performance gets worse the more pixels have to be rendered, aka a bigger window/bigger image. It also gets worse if the scaling mode is on a higher quality like bilinear.

I even tried to leverage aforge's scaling filters thinking maybe they'd be more optimized, but they seem about the same.

I also thought maybe setting up threading/multicore for rendering would be a good idea, but that seems very difficult and out of the question.

Comment: @FakeName *"but that misses the point of what I'm doing"* - What is the point of what you are doing? It is not clear.

Comment: @FakeName As Simon Mourier pointed out, you can only take advantage of the GPU's power when you do image processing (applying filters like you do, resampling etc. ). You don't get much use out of this power when you're just drawing an image into a window.

Comment: You should provide a reproducing sample to get more help https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example